# Insert django form into template dynamically using javascript?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I want to add same django form instance on same template. i already add one before and other add dynamically using javascript.

for example 'form" is a **django form**: `newcell.innerHTML = {{ form.firstname }};`
The problem is that when i submit the form, in view the request object has only one value (that is not add using javascript). how can i get the values of other form elements values that is added dynamically runtime.

**It is something like the "Attach Another File" feature in gmail, where the user is presented with a file upload field and new fields are added to the DOM on the fly as the user clicks to "Attach Another File" plus button**

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is. Please can you explain in a bit more detail.

Comment: It is something like the "Attach Another File" feature in gmail, where the user is presented with a file upload field and new fields are added to the DOM on the fly as the user clicks to "Attach Another File" plus button

Comment: I think you should show us more of your code. Based on what you said I think it is very likely you are in effect trying to pass multiple values to a single form field. You should take a look at "formsets" and "inline formsets".

Answer (score 0):

You could always try separating out your `FileField` into a `FileModel`.

Take a look at the following pseudo code (as in python based on memory--i've moved over to clojure for now).

`models.py`

```
class FileModel(models.Model):
  file = models.FileField()
  ...

class ThingToWhichYoureAttaching(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  attachments = models.ManyToManyField(FileModel)
  ...
```

`forms.py`

```
class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model=FileModel

class ThingForm(forms.ModelForm):
  attachments = forms.MultipleChoiceField()#override the manytomany form field with style field of your choice.
  class Meta:
    model=ThingToWhichYoureAttaching
```

When they pop up the window with the PLUS button, show the `FileForm` but on the main page leave the `ThingForm` untouched. You can also have an initial FileField on the main page with the `ThingForm` for people who don't have javascript. Just make sure to process the `FileForm` BEFORE the `ThingForm` so that the File is available for the Thing.

When processing the popup form you can use AJAX (i recommend [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)) to submit the FileForm to the server, and return the markup to insert the File in the Attachments field.